# Conclusion from PCA of dataset

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, lstm

I have a set of data for sequence labeling. 
I did PCA with (with 2 principal components on the x and y axis) on the dataset and it turns out as below:
[image: PCA of raw dataset]

Using an LSTM network to classify the dataset above, I then decided to extract the activations from the hidden layer of the LSTM. What I obtain is like the figure below:
[image: PCA of activation from LSTM hidden layer using the above dataset]

My question is, what conclusion can I draw by comparing both the results?
Is it fair to say that the features of the original dataset are now self-organized after running it through an LSTM classifier?

Comment: This is probably not on topic here as it is not a question about programming. Anyways, can you please at least say what exactly is plotted and what is on the axes?